# Some weird behaviour of JavaScript, can anybody please explain this

Tags: javascript

Please help me to understand the code below, how the values of 'a' , 'b' and 'c' are calculated.

```
var a = (1,5 + 10) * 5; //returns 75
var b = (0, "150", 30, 20, 38 + 10); //returns 48
var c = (5 & 3 + 10); // returns 5
```

Comment: Cannot understand what you are trying to get for example what should you get from this `var a = (1,5 +10)*5;`?

Comment: yes, i don't able to understand how javascript calulate this (1,5+10)*5 gives result 75

Answer (score 6):

`a` is set to be `(1, 5 + 10) * 5`. At the top level, it’s a multiplicative expression, multiplying `1, 5 + 10` by `5`. `1, 5 + 10` uses the comma operator, which first evaluates `1`, discards it, and then evaluates `5 + 10`, which evaluates to `15`, which is then multiplied by `5`, yielding `75`.

`b` works similarly, except it’s just got a lot of commas. It evaluates a lot of things, discards all their results, and finally goes on to evaluating the last one, `38 + 10`, which gives the result `48`.

`c` evaluates `5 & 3 + 10`. `&` has a lower precedence than `+`, so it’s actually `5 & (3 + 10)`. `3 + 10` is `13`, which is `1101` in binary; `5` is `101` in binary. Doing a bitwise AND on these two values yields `101`, which is again `5`, which is the result.

Answer (score 1):

---

To understand it more easily, "the comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand."

So (a, b,c, ... z) will evaluate everything but only return z.

In your example:

```
var a = (1,5 +10)*5;
```

1 is evaluated, then 5+10 (which is 15);15 is then returned and multiplied by 5.

The & operator does a bitwise AND on the numbers (ie. compare two binary numbers and for each position, return 1 if both numbers are 1).

```
0101 //5
1101 //13

0101
```

The last number is 5 in decimal